# Tomcat and JDBC driver

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, mocking

i have one webapp deployed on tomcat, that uses the JDBC driver's access to a remote db. my question is: how can i get in the middle, like a proxy, and mock the results (without changing a single line of Java code)?

example: there is a jdbc proxy that I can use?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have few options:

1. Use an embedded database such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/). It even has few [compatibility modes](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) with other databases, so you won't have to change your statements.
2. Use a mocking library like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), like Sanjay suggested.
3. Use [dbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for unit testing your database.
4. Install your remote database on your local computer, if it's feasible.

**Edit**: from your comment, it seems options 1 and 2 are of interest to you.

I haven't used mocking because I didn't need it yet (I prefer using the *real* stuff), but I don't say it isn't useful.

So, I will focus a bit on 1:

Check out H2's tutorial, specifically, the part about [connecting to database using JDBC](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc). Also, reading the [quickstart](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) guide can't hurt. You have to read to understand ;-)

For compatibility, check the link I provided earlier and use whatever mode that's suitable for the database you're using (you didn't specify which one).

Comment: respond to points:

1) my goal is to use a db locally, such as H2 ... but how?
2) as an alternative to db, Mock is a good solution ... but how ?
3) I do not want to test the db
4) the local installation is not provided and the purpose of my post is just to have one

Answer (score 0):

Without changing/adding a single line of code? Not that I know of. Of course if you have programmed to an interface and are planning to write JUnit tests for your code, you can look into a mocking library like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to do that job for you, though, the job of "creating" the data would yours to lookout for.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what are you trying to test? Do you want to verify your SQL-statements are correct? Or transaction boundaries? Or perhaps some data-processing inside your DAO-layer? Thinking of it that way may lead you to different conclusions about what needs mocking.

Comment: the goal is to speed up the use of the application (in development). the remote database slows down development.

Comment: Ah, ok. I absolutely love this one: http://hsqldb.org/ - so easy to run in the same vm as the rest and yet so fully featured. Perhaps that is a solution?